# ArchLinux(Guest) Installation VMWare 8 (Windows 7 Host) - Accessing Gnome3 DE using VNC, How?

Tags: xorg, vnc, arch-linux, vmware-workstation, gnome3

I have installed ArchLinux as guest OS on VMWare running on Windows 7 host.
I want to have a Gnome 3 GUI running.
I want to achieve that in a way that VMWare itself does not show the GUI.
Instead I want to access the full GUI using a VNC Client like RealVNC.

I followed the installation of ArchLinux VMWare from the official website, installed X, installed gnome3, installed x11vnc with all of the packages.

I do pacman -S to anything, but I can't seem to figure out how to achieve what I want.

Question: How can I access the gnome 3 UI from VNC Client? It says connection refused whenever I try to connect.
e. g. Using realVnc I try to connect to 192.168.180.240:1, the error that appears is:
Unable to connect to host: Connection refused. 10061

I have googled, looked into archlinux forum, asked on IRC. To no avail. If anyone can direct me to a layman article that would be great as well. I follow instructions well.
Pardon me if I overlooked something in following all those articles.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, can't comment just yet, but the problem sounds to me as though your VNC server is incorrectly configured.

Following the steps outlined at the [X11vnc ArchWiki page](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/X11vnc), on your server, make sure to:

1. Open a terminal in your X session and run the x11vnc server using: `$ x11vnc -display :0`
2. Assuming you're using GDM, running: `# x11vnc -display :0 -auth /var/lib/gdm/:0.Xauth`.

I'm not positive if the guide means for you to use the second one instead of the first.  It looks like it'll just fix potential problems you may have with authentication.

Basically I'm asking what you've tried from the [X11vnc ArchWiki page](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/X11vnc).